# PHP Checking the length of a SSN

Tags: php, regex

We're trying to setup an online application for our admissions office and we need to error check Social Security Numbers to make sure they've entered a valid value. Either `xxx-xx-xxxx` or just 9 digits. I've tried several iterations and this is what I'm on right now:

```
$ssn = $form_values['submitted_tree']['biographical_information']['social_security_number'];

if (strlen($ssn) > 0 && preg_match('/^([0-9]){3}(([ ]|[-])?([0-9]){2})(([ ]|[-])?([0-9]){4})?$/', $ssn) == 0) { 
    form_set_error('submitted][biographical_information][social_security_number', t('You must enter a valid Social Security Number: ###-##-####')); 
}
```

Comment: `/^(\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})$/` should do it

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply strip any `-` from the string and then verify that it is 9 digits?

```
$ssn = ...;
$ssn_validate = str_replace('-', '', $ssn);
$pattern = '/^[0-9]{9}$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $ssn_validate)) {
    // it matched
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
if( (is_numeric($ssn) && strlen($ssn) == 9)
   || preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/", $ssn) ){

    echo "valid";

} else {

    echo "invalid";

}
```

That will ensure the social security number is either purely 9 digits or follows the correct formatting (xxx-xx-xxxx)

Answer (score 2):

Since you aren't doing "real" SSN validation (for instance, they don't start with 0). I would just do a preg_replace for everything but numeric chars then you can just check the length to be == 9.

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$input);
```

Then you can allow people to enter the social however they want (xxx-xx-xxxx or xxx.xx.xxxx, etc.) and the validation still works. I do the same with phone numbers from time to time.

Comment: +1 I actually like this solution better than the one I proposed.

Comment: Wrong, SSN can start with 0, actually multiple 0s

Comment: @Manny Ramirez Agreed... I should have said they never start with consecutive 0's. They also never start with 666, or with 9's. At the end of the day... the answer would solve the OP's question so I'm not sure it was that big of a deal.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution:** strip all non-numeric characters, then validate what's left.

```
$ssn = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $ssn); // replace all non-digits
if(preg_match('~^\d{9}$~', $ssn)) { // look for exactly 9 digits
    echo "valid";
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

Note: this is the same concept as Matt Thompson's (correct) answer, but fleshed out more.

**If you want to do more accurate validation**, you can check that it doesn't have all zeros in any group and isn't a bogus number. (Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number#Valid_SSNs)):

```
$ssn = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $ssn); // replace all non-digits
if(preg_match('~^(?!000|666|9\d\d)\d{3}(?!00)\d{2}(?!0000)\d{4}$~', $ssn)) { // look for exactly 9 digits
    echo "valid";
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for validating SSN and formatting it properly, this will never fail:

```
function check_ssn($ssn){
    $clean_ssn = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $ssn);
    $formatted_ssn = preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/", "$1-$2-$3", $clean_ssn);
    // echo $formatted_ssn;
    if (preg_match ('/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/', $formatted_ssn)){
        $result = 1;
    } else $result = 0;
    return $result;
}
```